# QML's behavior depending on monitor used

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am using Qt's Example **Qt Quick Controls 2** with Qt v5.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I observe a different display behavior depending on the monitor I display on.

I have 2 monitors: my laptop's internal monitor and an external monitor. Both are 1920 x 1080.

When I display the app on the laptop's monitor I observe this:

[image]

When I display the app on the external monitor I observe this:

[image]

And the only thing I did to go from one to the other was drag the app from one monitor to the other.

The external monitor's display is good, not the laptop's display.

I observe this behavior with all QtQuick apps and I did not modify the code of example app **Qt Quick Controls 2**.

Any idea of what is going on?

**---------------EDIT----------------**

I have used the code below and have found that my internal display (Screen.width x Screen.height) is seen by QML as 960 x 540 and my external screen seen as 1920 x 1080. My internal screen should also be 960 x 540!

**Any idea why QML thinks my internal screen is 960 x 540, when it should be 1920x1080?**

```
MouseArea
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked:
    {
        console.log("name  = "                  + Screen.name)
        console.log("width  = "                 + Screen.width)
        console.log("height  = "                + Screen.height)
        console.log("desktopAvailableWidth  = " + Screen.desktopAvailableWidth)
        console.log("desktopAvailableHeight = " + Screen.desktopAvailableHeight)
        console.log("pixelDensity   = "         + Screen.pixelDensity )
        console.log("virtualX = "               + Screen.virtualX)
        console.log("virtualY = "               + Screen.virtualY)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I believe you are making the application as full screen on bot displays. You can try to run the default application which you will get when you create a new `QtQuick app`. This will have some hard coded resolution. Compare these 2 outputs and see if you are getting same difference.

Comment: Do you specify the font size in points or in pixel? Read: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-highdpi.html https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html

Comment: @PraveenKumar: which function do you suggest to get the resolution? A bit lost here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I was using the **HighDpiScaling** option.

When I got rid of line

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

in the **main.cpp** loading the **main.qml** my problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to get Screen resolution:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")


MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {

    console.log("Height = " + Screen.desktopAvailableHeight)
    console.log("Width  = " + Screen.desktopAvailableWidth)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the MouseArea::onClick() returns 2815x1068 both screens. This is larger than my each of my screens resolution (1920x1080)... Weird, no?

Comment: I have updated your code (see EDIT in my initial post), and QML thinks my internal screen is 960 x 540, when it should be 1920x1080! The external screen is fine.

Comment: That means the screen resolution of both screens are different.

Comment: Both screens actually have the same resolution (1920x1080), which I was able to double checked in the **System settings**. Hum this is weird...

Comment: Thanks @Praveen Kumar, you have really helped me pinpoint my problem.

Comment: Thanks @derM, your contribution has also helped me going round the problem.